# Duda al sumar datos de una tabla

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo una barra de progreso de tareas que ya esta terminadas y tareas que no lo estan.

Tengo una tabla que se llama `estado` en donde `0` indica que la tarea no se ha completado y `1` para indicar lo contrario.

```
id | userid | titulo    | estado
---------------------------------
1  | 1      | tarea 01  | 0
2  | 1      | tarea 02  | 1
3  | 2      | tarea 03  | 0
4  | 3      | tarea 04  | 0
```

Lo que ho  yo hice es algo que me da verguenza mostrarlo y es por eso que escribo esta pregunta:

```
<?php
$cont = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tareas WHERE userid = '".$row['uid']."'");
$contc = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tareas WHERE userid = '".$row['uid']."' AND estado = 1");
echo $cont->rowCount(); // total de tareas

$a = $cont->rowCount(); //Total de activdades
$b = $contc->rowCount(); //Actividades resultas

if ($a != 0) {
    $resultado = $b * 100 / $a;
    } else {
        $resultado = '0';
}
?>

<div class="progress mt-3" style="height: 4px;">
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: <?=$resultado;?>%;" aria-valuenow="<?=$resultado;?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

La verdad, esto me da verguenza mostrarlo pero trate de sumas en una sola consulta los datos y tratando de agruparlos por usuario logueado, esto quiere decir que al loguearse el usuario tomo su `id` para ralacionar los datos y tareas, pero no logro agruparlo. De igual manera esto funciona bien, la barra de progreso se muestra bien segun las tareas completadas o no, pero mi idea es no hacer dos consultas para tener un solo resultado.

Agradezco de antemano y pido disculpas por la manera en realizar este trabajo.

Comment: ¿Es decir quieres obtener la sumatoria de las tareas hechas por cada usuario según su `id`?

Comment: Claro, es lo que hace el script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que no sabes hacer es obtener el resultado que ya has obtenido en PHP directamente en MySQL.

Te propongo entonces la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT userid,ROUND(IFNULL(resueltas,0)/total,2) progreso 
  FROM (
    SELECT userid,COUNT(*) total FROM sebastian GROUP BY 1
  ) c1 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT userid,COUNT(*) resueltas FROM sebastian
      WHERE estado=1
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) c2 USING(userid);
```

Obtenida a partir de este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE sebastian(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  userid int,
  titulo varchar(15),
  estado bool
  );
INSERT INTO sebastian (userid,titulo,estado) VALUES
  (1,'titulo 01',0),
  (1,'titulo 02',1),
  (2,'titulo 03',0),
  (3,'titulo 04',0);
```

Con la que obtendrás el resultado:

> ```
> 1 0,50
> 2 0,00
> 3 0,00
> ```

Por favor, indícame en los comentarios si te puedo explicar algo sobre la respuesta, o si tienes dificultades para integrarla en tu PHP. Será un placer ampliarla en lo que necesites.

Comment: Lo entiendo. Voy a intentar integrarlo a PHP sin preguntar, asi aprendo como resolverlo. Es interesante la consulta, debo aprender mas sobre base de datos. Muchas gracias David!!